# PostgreSQL selecting each row from two temporary tables and comparing their values

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have two tables, foo and bar that both have the same schema and rowtype

```
Table1

name varchar
id int
age int
```

Foo contains 300 records, and Bar contains 100 records. Is there a select statement that will let me compare every row in Foo with every row in bar to determine if foo.age > bar.age? So if it was a for loop in java it would look something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Foo.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < Bar.length; j++){
       //Select here if foo[i].age > bar[j].age
    }
}
```

EDIT FOLLOW UP QUESTION:

If I have a temporary table called 'foobar', with the same schema as in 'Table 1' How can I insert the rows into foobar that are only part of foo into the temporary table. For example in java:

```
List list = new LinkedList<Table1>
for(int i = 0; i < Foo.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < Bar.length; j++){
       if(foo[i].age > bar[j].age){
            list.add(foo[i]);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from foo
  cross join bar
where foo.age > bar.age
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Can you have a look at the follow up question though, maybe you can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from foo cross join bar where foo.age > bar.age
```

will do this but i wonder why do you want to compare one entry to each and every entry in other table.